# Best fit of ellipse with given size and tilt to a set of points

Tags: conic-sections

I would need to fit a given ellipse to a set of points and I know its size and orientation. In other words, I want to find the best translation of a given ellipse to fit a set of points.
I have implemented a least squares fit like in this post : [How to find the best fit ellipse to a given set of 2D points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460536/how-to-find-the-best-fit-ellipse-to-a-given-set-of-2d-points) but how to include this known ellipse shape ?

This is what I did already :

Let's pose an ellipse with center $(h, k)$ and semiaxes a and b, and tilt $\theta$. $(a,b)$ and $\theta$ are known and I am looking for the best (h,k) given a set of of $n$ two-dimensional points $\{(x_i, y_i), i=1,.., n\}$.

I used the conic equation,

$$ A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0 $$

with the parametric to conic equations I have A, B and C known and
$$ A = (b\cos\theta) ^2 + (a\sin\theta)^2 $$
$$ B = -2\cos\theta\sin\theta(a^2-b^2) $$
$$ C = (b\sin\theta) ^2 + (a\cos\theta)^2 $$

So I have a linear system $ G a = b $

where $ a = [D, E, F]^T$, and

$ G = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 && y_1 && 1 \\
 x_2 && y_2 && 1 \\
 x_3 && y_3 && 1 \\
\vdots \\
 x_n && y_n && 1 \end{bmatrix}\hspace{5pt}, \hspace{25pt} b = \begin{bmatrix} - (Ax_1^2 +Bx_1y_1 + Cy_1^2) \\ - (Ax_2^2 +Bx_2y_2 + Cy_2^2) \\ - (Ax_3^2 +Bx_3y_2 + Cy_3^2) \\ \vdots \\ - (Ax_n^2 +Bx_ny_n + Cy_n^2) \end{bmatrix} $

By solving the equation I find an ellipse which definitely fit my set of points, but it also changes slightly the shape of my given ellipse, which is not what I want.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best fit ellipse has the equation

$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r0) = 1 $

where

$ r = [x,y]^T $ is the position vector of each of the data points, and $r_0=[h, k]^T$ is the center of the best fit ellipse, and $Q$ is given and is equal to,

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{a^2} \cos^2 \theta + \dfrac{1}{b^2} \sin^2 \theta && \cos \theta \sin \theta \bigg( \dfrac{1}{b^2} - \dfrac{1}{a^2} \bigg ) \\ \cos \theta \sin \theta \bigg( \dfrac{1}{b^2} - \dfrac{1}{a^2} \bigg) && \dfrac{1}{a^2} \sin^2 \theta + \dfrac{1}{b^2} \cos^2 \theta \end{bmatrix} $

The error function to be minimized is the sum of the squared errors from the above ellipse model and is given by

$ E = \displaystyle \sum_i \bigg( (r_i - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0 ) - 1  \bigg)^2 = \sum_i \bigg( r_i^T Q r_i - 2 r_i^T Q r_0 + r_0^T Q r_0 - 1 \bigg)^2 $

The gradient of $E$ with respect to $r_0$ is given by

$ \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial r_0} = \displaystyle 2 \sum_i \bigg(  r_i^T Q r_i - 2 r_i^T Q r_0 + r_0^T Q r_0 - 1 \bigg) \bigg( - 2 Q (r_i - r_0) \bigg) = 0 $

The above equation is a set of $2$ equations in the two unknowns $r_{0x} = h $ and $r_{0y}= k $

Since these equations are nonlinear, we can use the well-known multivariate Newton-Raphson method to find the solution.

Simply select an initial guess of $r_0$, let's call it $r_0^{(0)} $, for $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots $ you can generate the next guess as follows

1. Set $ y^{(k)} = \displaystyle \sum_i \bigg(  r_i^T Q r_i - 2 r_i^T Q r_0^{(k)} + {r_0^{(k)}}^T Q {r_0^{(k)}} - 1 \bigg) \bigg( Q (r_i - r_0^{(k)}) \bigg) $
2. Calculate the Jacobian matrix $J = [J_{ij} ]= \bigg[ \dfrac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j} \bigg]$, where $x_1 = r_{0x}$, and $x_2 = r_{0y} $
3. Update the estimate of the solution by the Newton-Raphson recurrence

$$ r_{0}^{(k+1)} = r_{0}^{(k)} - J^{-1} y^{(k)} $$

4. Stop when $\| y^{(k)} \| \le \epsilon $

---

To calculate the Jacobian, define

$ v_i = r_i - {r_0}^{(k)}$

$ f_i = {v_i}^T Q {v_i} - 1 $

Then

$ y^{(k)} = \displaystyle \sum_i f_i Q v_i $

Then by direct differentiation, we have

$ J =\displaystyle \sum_i \bigg( -2 Q v_i v_i^T Q - f_i Q \bigg) $

---

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer ! This may be trivial to you but could you please detail how you would calculate this Jacobian matrix J ?

Comment: I've appended my solution to include how to calculate the Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working great !

Comment: @BLegu You're welcome, glad I could help.