Least Squares Ellipse with known parameters
Given a set of points in 2D space
$$P = \{(x_i, y_i), \text{for } i \text{ in }1 \dots N\}$$
I want to find the least squares fit of an ellipse
$$\frac{(x - c_x)^2}{r_x^2} + \frac{(y - c_y)^2}{r_y^2} = 1$$
I have tried implementing Direct Least Square Fitting of Ellipses by A. Fitzgibbon but the results were not feasible for some of my test cases. Later I read in Numerically stable least squares fitting of ellipses by R. Halíř that the solution can be unstable when the points lie directly on the ellipse, which was my case. This solution works for me as an unconstrained ellipse least squares solution.
Now let's say I know some of the ellipse parameters, namely:

$\theta = 0$ my ellipse is axis aligned
$c_x$ and $r_x$ are known

How do I reformulate the equations to incorporate the priors into the solution? Should I use an entirely different method? Can this be formulated in a closed form?

Can be, but also can be noisy around it

See if this can be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572850/best-fit-of-ellipse-with-given-size-and-tilt-to-a-set-of-points
